# LinkedIn oAuth RequestToken "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: c#, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am attempting to acquire a RequestToken for the LinkedIn API via oAuth. I have tried numerous things and read all of the documentation I can find related to the topic, and consiquently tried all of the solutions I could think of.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetAccessToken()
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string url = string.Format("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        string header = string.Format(@"OAuth oauth_nonce=""{0}"", oauth_signature_method=""{1}"", oauth_timestamp=""{2}"", oauth_consumer_key=""{3}"", oauth_signature=""{4}"", oauth_version=""{5}""",
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GenerateNonce()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(getSignatureMethod()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GenerateTimeStamp()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(getClientID()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(getClientSecret()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(getVersion()));

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
        request.Method = "POST";

        HRArtis_Security.MyProxy HRProxy = new HRArtis_Security.MyProxy();
        request.Proxy = HRProxy;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in retVal.Split('&'))
            {
                tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                    token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
            }
        }
        return tokens;
    }
```

I then perform a POST to that URL.
The error occurs when trying to get the response with the line `HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse`

Another option I tried was adding those parameters to the header with no result.

Am I missing something or being an idiot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you have misconfigured oAuth header. I suggest you to use *Hammock* or *RestSharp* library to authorize with LinkedIn. Here are several examples how to do this: [Hammock](http://www.suddenelfilio.net/2010/08/24/linkedin-oauth-using-hammock-in-csharp-asp-net/) and [RestSharp](https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs) (LinkedIn and Twitter both are using oAuth v1.0).

Comment: I had a look at those previously. But I'll give them a shot and see if it works out(if it does I'll mark your answer as accepted) :). Thank you.

Comment: I managed to implement the RestSharp library. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great! Do not forget to save *oauth verifier* if you like to get permanent authorization using *accessToken*. This is a difference between LinkedIn and Twitter OAuth implementation.

Comment: I've jumped ahead and have the accessToken already. Once I had the requestToken cracked the rest wasn't hard. Thanks again =). I had previously used the Facebook API, which is also slightly different.